# Is it possible to get unique id for every client in Firebase without using custom authentication?

Tags: authentication, firebase

I'm currently using Google authentication provided by Firebase, but I need to generate a unique id for each client connected to Firebase, i.e. even if user is logged in with the same Google account on 2 different devices, I'd like to have a different id in `auth` object.

I want to do WebRTC signaling over Firebase and I need to be able to uniquely identify a device (even if a user is logged in with the same account on all of them). I also would like to have this id in `auth` object, so that I can use it in security rules to define that e.g. only given device can read messages sent to it.

Is it possible to do it without custom authentication and generating JWT token on the server? I'd like to add more providers in the future, so I'd really like to avoid handling it myself.

Comment: Interesting use-case. For this use-case it would be really nice if there also was a `auth.deviceid` property, but that doesn't exist. Right now I can't think non-custom-JWT way way to implement this, but I'll keep brooding for a bit.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thanks. I'm currently using Firebase for WebRTC signaling in my other app - https://www.sharedrop.io, but there I have a kind of anonymous auth - I automatically generate custom JWT token for every user who visits the page to get this custom identifier in `auth` object. I implemented it about 2 years ago - I guess it was before Firebase introduced built-in anonymous auth.

Anyway, any chances to get this `auth.deviceId` in any near future? :)

Comment: Not without custom auth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Not without custom auth. – Frank van Puffelen